# Grey box appears when CTRL+Tab in Netbeans on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans, java

I've been using Netbeans on Ubuntu for years.  A long-standing problem I've had is when I CTRL + Tab between windows in it and occasionally I get a grey box appearing in the centre of the screen.  Although its not a major problem (I have to restart Netbeans to get rid of it), it is irritating.

Does anyone know how I can permanently get rid of it?

**Current Setup**
Netbeans 7.2.1 - has happened since 6.9
Ubuntu 12.10
Oracle Java 1.7.0_11 - happens when I use Java 6/7 and OpenJDK 6/7 too

Comment: Having exact same problem. Extremely annoying! Anyone got a solution yet?

Comment: No. A wall of silence has greeted this question...

Comment: Just found this question realised I've not seen it for quite some time. There's Netbeans 7.3 been released since then, so I suspect the bug's been fixed